# Sort an array of objects based on a property value, but the property is a string that includes a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to sort an array of objects based on a property value, but the property is a string that includes a number. For example, I have an array of objects like this:

```
const data = [
 { name: 'Item 1', value: '2 apples' },
 { name: 'Item 2', value: '10 oranges' },
 { name: 'Item 3', value: '1 banana' },
 { name: 'Item 4', value: '5 strawberries' }
];
```

I want to sort the array by the numeric value in the value property, so that the sorted array looks like this:

```
[  { name: 'Item 3', value: '1 banana' },  { name: 'Item 1', value: '2 apples' },  { name: 'Item 4', value: '5 strawberries' },  { name: 'Item 2', value: '10 oranges' }]
```

Here is my code which is not working

```
data=data.sort((a,b) => b.value-a.value)
```

One solution can be: "*split value on space then get number from 0th index and then compare*". Is there any better way of sorting?

Comment: Will the numbers always be at the start of the string? Will they ever have any thousands or decimal separators?

Comment: What will be the order of numeric value in the `value` property ? It will always be at starting, end or at any place in that value. Will this work ? https://jsfiddle.net/xsrj8c6y/

Comment: Yes it'll always at the start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data.sort((a, b) => {
const numA = parseInt(a.value);
const numB = parseInt(b.value);
return numA - numB;
});
```

Try with above logic, it should work

Answer (score 1):

You could use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` to convert the `value` into a number and then do the sorting algorithm:

```js
parseFloat('10 oranges'); // 10
```

> Note: this only works when the number always appears at the beginning of the string.

```js
const data = [
 { name: 'Item 1', value: '2 apples' },
 { name: 'Item 2', value: '10 oranges' },
 { name: 'Item 3', value: '1 banana' },
 { name: 'Item 4', value: '5 strawberries' }
];

const output = data.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.value) - parseFloat(b.value));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: “this only works when the number always appears at the beginning of the string”: I would add: apart from whitespace (space, tab, newline, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` and regex to extract numbers to sort:

```js
const data = [
    { name: 'Item 1', value: '2 apples' },
    { name: 'Item 2', value: '10 oranges' },
    { name: 'Item 3', value: '1 banana' },
    { name: 'Item 4', value: '5 strawberries' }
   ];
   

const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.value.replace(/\D/g, "")) - parseInt(b.value.replace(/\D/g,"")));
console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `extractNumber` function extracts the first number found in a string using a regular expression (`/\d+/`) and then returns it as an integer using `parseInt()`. If no number is found, it returns 0. Then the function is used inside the sort method to compare the numbers.

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'Item 1', value: '2 apples' },
  { name: 'Item 2', value: '10 oranges' },
  { name: 'Item 3', value: '1 banana' },
  { name: 'Item 4', value: '5 strawberries' }
];

const extractNumber = (str) => {
  const num = str.match(/\d+/);
  return num ? parseInt(num[0]) : 0;
};

const sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => extractNumber(a.value) - extractNumber(b.value));

console.log(sortedData);
```